# How to test iPhone app with different n/w speed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I wants to test my iPhone app performance with different n/w speed on device.

can any one suggest me any Mac application or test environment where I can test it?

Currently I am testing app by creating my Mac as hot spot.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need very fine granularity regarding the tested speeds you could just load the App onto the device and test with Wifi, 3G and Edge/GPRS. Most of the times this should suffice I'd say, its also the speeds users will likely encounter in real life.

Answer (score 1):

I had a network issue when it would drop a connection mid transfer... my top tip was put the app on your test device and chuck the phone in a microwave ( needless to say without turning it on of course! ) and look at the crash logs for what on earth happened.

The faraday cage works a charm to test that 'travelling in a train' style loss of signal that inevitably happens outside of the office environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://mschrag.github.com/ to test in the simulator

Answer (score 0):

I'd say test it on the Real Device first. If your App is consuming Web Services somewhere , try to test that for times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 4.1 on Lion, you can use the Network Link Conditioner pref pane provided. It can be found under /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Network Link Conditioner.

[image]